# Initialize Slider in materialize css

Tags: javascript, html, css, materialize

I copied the example code for the materialize slider and pasted it into my html. 
I linked the html with a JavaScript file, where I placed an

```
M.AutoInit();
```

Which should initialize all JS components of `materialize.css`
(Carousel works in my html)

This is the related html:

```html
<div class="row ">
    <div class="col s12 m12 ">
        <div class="slider">
            <ul class="slides">
                <li>
                    <img src="https://lorempixel.com/580/250/nature/4">
                    <!-- random image -->
                    <div class="caption center-align">
                        <h3>This is our big Tagline!</h3>
                        <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Here's our small slogan.</h5>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is how I linked to the JavaScript: First `materialize.js` that `app.js` where I `M.AutoInit();`

```html
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="../js/materialize.js"></script>
<!-- <script type="text/JavaScript" src="../js/materialize.min.js"></script> -->
<script src="../app.js "></script>
</html>
```

I am confused, because the carousel works within the same setting but not the slider…

Comment: Are you trying to implement Range? https://materializecss.com/range.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 things to change in your code:

1. Make sure your initialization code is executed just after the DOM Content is totally loaded
2. Use the specific initializator of the slider instead of the generic one

```
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.slider');
    var instances = M.Slider.init(elems);
  });
```

Working example with your code: https://codepen.io/jhervas/pen/mddNrZX

Comment: I made the mistake in copying the code from materialize.css without checking it carefully. The variable "instances" contains an argument called "options". (On the materialize.css page) In your code you omit "options" – because it is not specified. So it works. Thanks!